# Bootstrap datepicker only works on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to adapt the bootstrap datepicker on my site for a bit but I could not get it working. I decided to use a basic bootstrap set-up to try and get the date picker working. Having copied the basic markup from the Bootstrap website and imported all the relevant scripts and css files according to [Eonasdan - Bootstrap 3 datetime picker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), I got the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2> test</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moment/moment/develop/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I used [Datepicker with jQuery UI and Bootstrap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PG6q17Gppv0) to form the above code. 
My issue is that this only works on Firefox. How do I get it to work on all browsers?

Comment: you need to add the cdn versions of those js includes. The raw github links wont load properly. It's working fine on chrome once I change all the resources to cdn versions: http://jsfiddle.net/ame51gq8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't link directly to `https://raw.gitbuhusercontent.com/` because GitHub uses `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` which doesn't allow browsers to guess the type of the content you are using. So if you link to `https://raw.gitbuhusercontent.com/`, the browser reads it as `'text/plain'` and can't execute it as javascript.

Simply replace `https://raw.gitbuhusercontent.com/` with `https://cdn.rawgit.com/` in your javascript links.

By example :

`<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moment/moment/develop/moment.js"></script>`

to

`<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/moment/moment/develop/moment.js"></script>`